# Image not displaying in phaser 3

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

Recently I started making a game with Phaser 3.

I made an image *player.png*. Now comes the weird part. Whenever I try to display player.png it won't display on screen. Path, filename, console everything is correct. Code also has no errors. Now when I replaced the png image with another image. Surprise! It shows up. In fact any other image would be displayed other than player.png.

Please can anyone figure out why?

Comment: could be format issue. try opening your image in something like photoshop and save it again as png.

Comment: Well I made my image in inkscape. Could it be an issue. Thanks.

Comment: try re-saving it in photoshop

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.

Comment: mmm maybe you have player.png.png instead of player.png? can you try different image and save it as player.png and see if it works?

Comment: Ok well it was a format issue. I made the image again and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: toit! ill take the points :) hahaha

Answer (score 0):

could be format issue. try opening your image in something like photoshop and save it again as png.